# Can I submit iPhone applications with same Icon.png but differnt bundle name

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, submission

Can some one tell me if it is possible to submit two different iphone applications which has same Icon.png but have a different bundle name?

I am working on a travel guide app that is targeted for different cities. I want the users of different cities to download the app as per their cities. So I want to submit different apps for different cities(3 in my case).

User can also purchase any of these cities through in-app purchase. In that case the new purchased city would be unlocked in the app.

Here is my thing. I want the same icon for all the three apps. I can do away with different names for app store and bundle(home screen icon name).

But I am not sure if apple would approve/reject this app.

Can someone enhance this blur picture I have?

Answer (score 2):

Would an altogether simpler solution not be to have the base app be free, with previews of the data; and then using in-app purchase to fill it out once they have downloaded the app, hence obviating the need for multiple applications?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Wil

Nope. Nothingz for free!
Its just that we would the experience to be seamless and sale the user what he needs based upon his choice of city. We cannot provide any city by default. For ex, if we provide NY as default but the user wants SF....not friendly! So.

Comment: Then I would suggest having three skylines for icons.

Comment: @AJ - I agree with Williham on this, in-app purchase is the way to go.  You don't have to provide any city information for free, just the base application with three purchaseable guides.  Apple is encouraging you to go this route in order to cut down on clutter in the App Store.